# npm -g ERR! extraneous

Tags: node.js, npm

I've seen this in local node modules but not in global.

what is the cause and how can I prune these?

[image]

Comment: This question seems to cover what you need [npm windows install globally results in npm ERR! extraneous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620352/npm-windows-install-globally-results-in-npm-err-extraneous)

Comment: Can you remove them manually with `npm -g uninstall <packagename>`?

Comment: @JoshW I'm osx. so no it doesn't cover the issue. I'm using `n` version manager and homebrew installed original node.

Comment: @brandonscript nope they don't go away

Comment: Open a ticket with npm then I'd say

Comment: @brandonscript okay. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15436

Answer (score 7, accepted):

reinstalling npm fixed this problem: `npm i -g npm@latest`

Comment: Don't do this with npm in plesk, after this it will not work anymore.