# Do not show npm ERR! extraneous when listing packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed some packages with npm globally and some only locally within the folder of my project. When I want to list all locally installed packages in the folder with the command `npm list --depth=0` I get a lot of these errors: `npm ERR! extraneous`. I guess this is because some packages are already installed globally as dependencies. This seems to be no big issue. However, all these errors are pretty annoying. Is there a solution how to hide these?

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620352/npm-windows-install-globally-results-in-npm-err-extraneous).

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I am searching for. The top answer just confirms what I already supposed, that this error is indeed harmless. The second answer doesn't work for me. Another answer suggests to install all packages globally, but this is also not what I desire. 

Whenever I want to list my local packages in one folder I face dozens of lines of the error. I would like to suppress, hide or filter these out,  to see the locally installed packages easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is a bit dirty since it uses an additional `grep` command, but it perfectly does the job (on Unix-like terminals):

```
npm list --depth=0 2> >(grep -v "extraneous")
```

It can be easily generalized to other types of errors or warnings the user wishes to keep hidden.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I thought about grep as well, but didn't manage to get working with the output of `npm list`.

Comment: You're welcome! The error messages from Unix commands are sent differently to the standard output, so a simple pipe `|` won't work indeed.

Answer (score 2):

To suppress npm errors I followed the answer mentioned here: [Can I hide or silence "npm ERR!" output when using npm run script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084112/can-i-hide-or-silence-npm-err-output-when-using-npm-run-script)

The command is just extended by the option `-s` which stands for `--silent`.
This command works now as desired: `npm list -s --depth=0`